# Angular 2, Node js Error npm run server:prod

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, npm

I have an error trying to run the project in production,

When running npm run build: prod compiles me without errors, but when running npm run server: prod pass this:

```
C:\Users\Prueba Tecnica\Venfi> npm run server:prod

> venfi@3.3.0 server:prod C:\Users\Prueba Tecnica\Venfi
> http-server dist --cors

events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1257:14)
at listen (net.js:1293:10)
at net.js:1403:9
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:prod"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! venfi@3.3.0 server:prod: `http-server dist --cors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the venfi@3.3.0 server:prod script 'http-server dist --cors'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the venfi package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server dist --cors
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs venfi
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls venfi
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Prueba Tecnica\Venfi\npm-debug.log
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not node JS error, 
Something is already running on Port 8080.

Kill that & run this again .!
Steps to kill a process on a port.

1. Type netstat -a -o -n and it will bring up a network list, look at the PID (e.g. 8080).

2 .To find out what PID 8080 was (hopefully not a trojan) I typed tasklist /FI “PID eq 8080″

3. To kill it type taskkill /F /PID 2600  [whatever processId i get in above step.]

Answer (score 0):

Port is already in use. Just open your task manager on what ever OS you are on and kill any node processes. When using node stuff from the cli remember to kill the proccess by pressing ctrl + c when its running. Sometimes if you just close the terminal using X button it will close the terminal but leave the process running it the background. If all else fails and you can't get rid of the message just reboot the computer.